# Token holdings I need help with the contract im the owner of both wallets the send and receiver

Tags: transactions, tokens, smart-contract-wallets, address.transfer, wallet-transfer

I sent my tokens to another wallet that I own and somehow a contract intercepted it and my tokens are in holding. I believe I can get them back it’s just really confusing to r we the contact and I don’t know what I’m supposed to write.
Name

Transfer (index_topic_1 address from, index_topic_2 address to, uint256 value)View Source